# Multiple duplicated rows returned on GROUP BY query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following mysql query thinking it would give me a table of unique rows grouped by fields given. I end up with a few rows where the grouped by fields are duplicated but the unique id and count are the only thing that's different.

There are tens of thousands of rows, but only a couple hundred that are repeated with no visible difference in the field. What might cause this?

```
 CREATE TABLE group_avg_product_prices AS
        SELECT group_id,
        feature_1, 
        feature_2, 
        feature_3,
        AVG(price) AS avg_price,
        count(*) AS sample_count, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(unique_id SEPARATOR ",") AS items
 FROM products_table
 GROUP BY group_id,
          feature_1, 
          feature_2, 
          feature_3
```

returns rows that are something like:

```
asdf123 | 2 | 1| .5| 2.65| 3| id1,id2,id3
asdf123 | 2 | 1| .5| 2.34| 2| id4,id5
```

It's driving me nuts and I can't find any reason why it might do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: That would be really helpful if I could. Unfortunately there are 30,000+ rows and it only happens on ~200 of them.

Comment: Create for the data that is causing problems.

Comment: You need to post more sample data.   Post sample schema that produces the result in your sample output.  Also provide a sample output of what you are looking for it to produce.  This helps people get a better idea of what we are dealing with.  Thanks.

Comment: Seeing your example shows .5 as feature_3, is this a float, double or real column? These may not behave as expected because it may depend on how they were originally calculated whether they are the same or not. A difference that may not be able to be displayed. Maybe these columns can be converted to decimal or something other with an exact representation.

Comment: Im still not clear on what you want the result to come out as.

Comment: I tried manually inserting and grouping a small group of them, but they seem to group fine. The products table is derived from various sources with conditional elements as to where it gets the information. Is there a way to see if there is a non-visisble difference between the data in these columns?

Comment: @AuntJamaima what data types are the columns stored as?

Comment: isn't the difference the ID column?  ??

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 i don't think it's the ID, probably the data types.

Comment: Try  `CAST(feature3 AS DECIMAL(..,1)` if it's defined as a REAL, etc.

Comment: @Notorious. The two rows in the example above should all be on the same line with a count of 5 and an average of 2.53 and a product id list of id1 thru id5.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, the fourth column is numeric.  It might *look* like 0.5, but the values are probably different, such as 0.499999 and 0.500001.

My suggestion is to use `format()` -- either on the output so you can see the difference, or in the query itself.  For instance, to combine two rows with similar values up to the first decimal place:

```
 SELECT group_id, feature_1,  feature_2, 
        format(feature_3, 1) as feature_3,
        AVG(price) AS avg_price,
        count(*) AS sample_count, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(unique_id SEPARATOR ',') AS items
 FROM products_table
 GROUP BY group_id, feature_1, feature_2, 
          format(feature_3, 1);
```